# undefined method `and' for #<Arel::Attributes::Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, arel

I'm having an issue getting a query to work.

I'm essentially trying to write something like the following SQL, with the literal `5` replaced with a variable:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "my_table"
WHERE 5 BETWEEN "my_table"."minimum" AND "my_table"."maximum"
```

This is what I have at the moment:

```
    MyModel.where(
      Arel::Nodes::Between.new(
        my_variable, (MyModel.arel_table[:minimum]).and(MyModel.arel_table[:maximum])
      )
    )
```

Please ignore the way I am using `arel_table`, the actual query has  multiple joins and is more complex, but this is the most minimum reproducible example I have to demonstrate the problem.

The error, as in the subject of the question is as follows:

```
undefined method `and' for #<Arel::Attributes::Attribute:0x00007f55e15514f8>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`and` method is for `Arel::Nodes::Node` i.e. `MyModel.arel_attribute[:name].eq(Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new('engineersmnky'))` This is an `Arel::Nodes::Equality` and you can chain with `and`.

That being said you can construct an `Arel::Nodes::And` for yourself via

```
Arel::Nodes::And.new([left,right])
```

Then we can pass this to the `Between` class like so

```
Arel::Nodes::Between.new(
  Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new(my_variable),
  Arel::Nodes::And.new([
    MyModel.arel_table[:minimum], 
    MyModel.arel_table[:maximum]])
)
```

The `Arel::Nodes::Quoted` (also: `Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(arg)`) is not needed in your case since your `my_variable` is an `Integer` which can be visited and will be treated as an `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral` but I find it best to let arel decide how to handle the quoting in case your `my_variable` ends up being some other un-visitable `Object`

There are other ways to create a `Between` and other ways to create an `And` depending on what objects you are dealing with.

`between` is a `Arel::Predication` and these predications are available to `Arel::Nodes::Attribute` objects e.g.

```
 MyModel.arel_table[:minimum].between([1,6])
```

`and` as mentioned is available to `Arel::Nodes::Node` and instances of this class provides a convenience method (`create_and`) for creating an `And` so we could do the following:

```
Arel::Nodes::Node.new.create_and([
     MyModel.arel_table[:minimum],
     MyModel.arel_table[:maximum]])
```

There are a number of other ways to hack this functionality together by using other `Arel` classes but this should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Amazing insight and solution, thank you very much!